# Android - Lost my way in this multithreaded approach - pass data and thread execution to higher hierarchy object

Tags: java, android, multithreading, parameter-passing, hierarchy

I really cannot think anymore, somehow I am almost at the end but now I hope, this will not be a dead-end-street.

I want to pass data from a inherited thread object back to my parent object.
And also return to main thread all in one.

Here is my Parent-Object

```
public class ControllerBase implements IController , IHandleRequestOnChange, IHandlesCustomTimer{ 
     private QueueWorkerThread _QueueWorker;        

     // some other vars and methods

     // ctor and so on .....


    // initializer 

    public void init(){ 
     // some other code
     _QueueWorker = new QueueWorker();
     _QueueWorker.SetEventListener(this);     // i want to announce this object from _QueueWorker
     _QueueWorker.start()                     // starts the thread

    // other initializations
    }

   @Override
   public void OnQueueWorkerReady(DataToPass){
      // from IHandleRequestOnChange

      // ALL INSIDE THIS CODE SHALL BE PROCESSED IN UI THREAD. BUT HOW ?
      DataReceived dataRec = new DataReceived();

      dataRec =  this.Request(DataToPAss);  
      this.ApplyDataToUIControls(dataRec);
   }

}
```

Here is my QueueWorkerThread :

```
public class QueueWorkerThread extends Thread implements IRequestQueueProcessed{

  // ctor
  public QueueWorkingThread(){
    super();        
  }

 // other variables and methods
  IHandlesRequestOnChange _Listener;

 public void Enque(DataToPass Data){
     this.add(Data);
 }

 public void SetEventListener( IHandlesRequestOnChange pEventListener) {
    this._Listener = pEventListener;
 @Override 
 public void run(){
    // here a LinkedBlockingQueue is polled
    // AND UNDER SOME CONDITIONS I WANT TO PASS THE POLLED DATA BACK TO 
    // THE PARENT OBJECT AND RETURN TO MAIN THREAD. HOW CAN I ACHIEVE THIS?

    if(AcertainConditionIsMet == true){
       // I want to return to UI thread
        this.OnQueueWorkerReady(the_polled_data)
    }

    // and this thread shall proceed and do some other stuff......
 }


@Override 
public void OnQueueWorkerReady(TableToPass Data){
 // of interface  IRequestQueueProcessed
 //  
 // calling parents callback via interface-casting
 ((IHandleRequestOnChange)_Listener).OnQueueWorkerReady(null, Data);    

 // this passes execution AND DATA to my parent object BUT I do not return to main thread

}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must share your handler in the application object to be able to pass data back in handler's message. You could have for instance:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private Handler handler;
    public Handler getHandler(){ return handler;}
    public void setHandler(Handler handler){ this.handler = handler;}
    private static MyApplication instance;
    public static MyApplication getMyApplication(){return instance;}
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    instance = this;
}

}
```

Notice the static method to be able to retrieve the application object without a context (like in your thread).

I suppose if you want to update your UI you should be inside some activity context, so in your activity, you declare the handler:

```
private Handler handler;
```

inside onCreate(), you can instantiate and store the handler in the app object:

```
handler = new Handler(){
public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
    //In here you can do your UI update using the references to the views   
}
};
((MyApplication)getApplication()).setHandler(handler);
```

**EDIT:**
You can now get an instance of your app object from your thread using the public static method..

Hope it helps.

Comment: THX. My parent object itself is an instance variable inside my fragment activity, there I already fetched the context,so this is done. But what inside my thread-object will ensure, that handler is called in main thread? Inside the scope of handle message I have no access to the two methods of parent object, which i want to call. Until now I used runOnUiThread, what gave me the same problem, so I cannot use this handle message approach.
And, what happens to all my other eventhandling inside the parent object(controller), when I use setHandler ? Will it be disturbed(Timer elapsed and so on)...

Comment: When you create a Handler (as first) in your main thread, you'll get the stuff done in the main thread. I think you'll do better using a broadcast that you can register for. If your parent object is an instance variable, then you can receive the intent in your fragment activity, and create a method you can call in your 'parent'. Regards. **My friend, multithreading is a headache...that's why I love it!**

Comment: I will create a class, which implements runnable ,also implements an own interface and also gets controller as listener and will call a method of the controller. I will have to use one step more if i want to use activity.runonuithread. though i think passing activity the hierarchy downwards is not recommended and may cause memor leak. What Do You think?

Comment: Agree with you. That's a possible solution. Even though I would recommend you (don't risk to leak the activity) to broadcast an Intent for the UI update with the data you want as a Serializable object as an extra. Don't forget that your thread/controller object(s) will live as long as the app object lives. So you can always use the app object as a "shared memory" space for your threads and all the data that can be passed in between. That's often more simple than creating a more complex hierarchy. Let me know if you succeed.

Comment: My mentioned approach succeeded.  But I do not really understand, what You mean by Broadcast. Was not on intents until now.

Comment: I was reading about receiving the default looper. Would like to know if i can obtain it inside my threadobject AND it would return me the main thread message pump in order to avoid my extra class which implements Runnable and avoid the corresponding other interface and avoid passing the activity-reference downwards to my controller object. Could this be done in some way?

Comment: I recommended you to use android.os.Handler in the first place 'cause you can post Runnables and Messages from other contexts. When you create the Handler in the main thread of your activity context (using the first approach), it's gonna be associated to the Looper of the calling thread, in your case, the **main thread** that is your goal.

Comment: If you create your thread object in the main thread, you can have access to the main Looper. Check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html